# msg plugin in ajax request

Tags: jquery

I am currently looking at this [plugin](http://dreamerslab.com/demos/jquery-blockui-alternative-with-jquery-msg-plugin) as blockui does not seem to work for me. I am using:

```
beforeSend: function () {
    $.msg({
    autoUnblock: false
    });
}
```

and would like to 'unblock' it in success, error etc.

Would this be possible? Thanks.

Comment: why blockui  is not working

Comment: is it not working or not suitable for you

Comment: I have no idea ... the above works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

i just tested and it works try like this:

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <link media="screen" href="https://raw.github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.msg/master/jquery.msg.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://raw.github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.msg/master/jquery.center.min.js"></script>

  <script src="https://raw.github.com/dreamerslab/jquery.msg/master/jquery.msg.min.js"></script>


<meta charset=utf-8 />
<title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**jQuery**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$.ajax({
  url: "http://www.google.com",
  beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
      $("#test").html("before send");
    $.msg({
    autoUnblock: false
    });
  },
  success:function(){
    $("#test").html("success");
      $.msg('unblock'); //this will remove the msg box
  },
  error:function(){
     $("#test").html("error");
    $.msg('unblock'); //this will remove the msg box
  }
});
});
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qqjhB/1/

In this sample code you will first go into  `beforesend` block so it will show you the msg box & then it will endup in `error` block then it will remove that msg box.

Comment: thanks. tried something similar but had message box appear in the top left corner. will try your approach tomorrow.

Comment: @csetzkorn i just updated my answer so please try this . It worked fine for me.